# overridePendingTransition only for the exit animation

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to use overridePendingTransition only for the exit animation? Or is there another similar function to do this?

The problem is that I'm using this after I close an activity and I'm starting another activity right after and overridePendingTransition seems to affect the enter animation for the second activity too.

This is my code:

```
public static void close() {
    activity.finish();
    activity.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}
```

I have tried doing it in styles.xml too but the exit animation is ignored for translucent activities (using windowIsTranslucent set to true). If I change windowIsTranslucent to false it will work for both enter and exit animations, but I need my activity to be transparent. Only overridePendingTransition works for both enter and exit animations. This is my xml code:

```
<style name="Animation">
    <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@null</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@null</item>
</style>
<style name="TranslucentTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/Animation</item>
</style>
```

Is there any solution to this problem? Thanks!